# Postgresql unrecognized, even though it's installed

Tags: linux, redhat, postgresql, yum

Postgresql 8.4 seems to be installed properly, according to this:

```
sudo yum install postgresql 
Loaded plugins: product-id, refresh-packagekit, rhnplugin, security, subscription-manager 
This system is not registered to Red Hat Subscription Management. You can
use subscription-manager to register. 
This system is receiving updates from RHN Classic or RHN Satellite. 
Setting up Install Process 
Package postgresql-8.4.13-1.el6_3.x86_64 already installed and latest version
Nothing to do
```

However, when I try to run this, it's unrecognized:

```
$ sudo /sbin/service postgresql initdb
postgresql: unrecognized service
```

This is RHEL 6.3

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You need to install postgresql-server to get the System V init scripts and server binaries.

Comment: Of course...  `sudo yum install postgresql-server` worked...